# Jquery checkbox calculator keeps returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, wordpress

i heve calucalot problem with jquery.
Custom Wpform Checkbox Field returning NaN.

HTML

```
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
    $ 85 
    </div>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="myBox2"  size="12" />
    With Two Coat + 15%
    <b><span id="totalfinal"></span> </b>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var Valuee = $('.wpforms-payment-total');
  jQuery('input[name="myBox2"]').on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
    var finalprice = parseInt($('.wpforms-payment-total').text()) * 1.15;
      jQuery('#totalfinal').text(finalprice.toFixed(2));
    } else {
      var finalprice = parseInt($('.wpforms-payment-total').text());
      jQuery('#totalfinal').text(finalprice.toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: `$('.wpforms-payment-total')/text()` is the text "$ 85" which can't be parsed as an int - very similar question about an hour ago, was that you? I gave you the answer, you remove the `$` before parsing it

Comment: @Bravo yes its was me i'm new sorry for repeat. im learning now and stuck here :( 

can you reply me solution ?

Comment: I did so in the previous question

Comment: `function editSalary() {
  var ns = $('.wpforms-payment-total').text();
  ns = ns.replace(/([,.$])+/g, '');
  $('.wpforms-payment-total').text(ns)
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
     editSalary();
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not parse any String to a number, you can either split your total amount in a prefix and a number oder you have to remove anything but the number from the string.

As I think storing the number in its own Tag makes more sense, here is a working snipet that does that.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
const Valuee = $('.wpforms-payment-total');
  jQuery('input[name="myBox2"]').on('click', function() {
    let finalprice = parseInt(Valuee.text().replace(/^[^0-9,.]+/, "").match( /^[0-9,.]+/g, '')[0]);
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      finalprice *= 1.15;
    }
    jQuery('#totalfinal').text(finalprice.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
  $ 85
</div>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="myBox2"  id="myBox2" size="12" />
<label for="myBox2">With Two Coat + 15%</label>
<br>
<b><span id="totalfinal"></span></b>
```

Here is another methode, using data attributes to make it more versityle, maybe that is something you might want to learn about when dealing with jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function updateTotalFinal(){
    const subtotalValue = +jQuery('.wpforms-payment-total').text().replace(/^[^0-9,.]+/, "").match( /^[0-9,.]+/g, '')[0];
    let totalValue = subtotalValue;
    const totalFinalElem = jQuery("#totalfinal");
    
    jQuery("input.change-total:checked").each(function() {
      const $this = jQuery(this);
      if ($this.is("[data-method=add]")) {
        totalValue += +$this.data("amount");
      } else if ($this.is("[data-method=multiply]")) {
        totalValue += subtotalValue * $this.data("amount");
      }
    });
    
    totalFinalElem.text(`$ ${totalValue}`);
  }
  
  jQuery("input.change-total").on("change", function() {
    updateTotalFinal();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
  85€
</div>
 
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="change-total" name="myBox2" size="12" data-amount="0.15" data-method="multiply" />
  With Two Coat + 15%
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="change-total" name="myBox3" size="12" data-amount="5" data-method="add" />
  With extra Pants + $ 5
</label>
<br>
<b><span id="totalfinal">$ 85</span></b>
```

Comment: Thank you !  but WP Forms  on `<div class="wpforms-payment-total"> </div>` automatically counting and typing there sum for ex.   `<div class="wpforms-payment-total">500$ </div>`

Comment: That would be a nice information to have :-) I changed my scripts accordingly.

Comment: Thank you sir ! 
but same problem i dont know what happaning :( https://imgur.com/qEX2fAX

Comment: That was most likely due to asyncronous issues, meaning that your total amount changes and this code was not considering that possibility, I changed it so it will work if the total changes. But you will have to trigger the updateTotalFinal function also when you change the total, to recalculate the totalfinal

Answer (score 1):

You must first remove all non-digits character from price then use that,

Notice that for `checkbox` it is better to use `change` event

```js
jQuery('input[name="myBox2"]').on('change', function() {
    
    // Remove any non-digits character 
    var price = parseInt($('.wpforms-payment-total').text().replace( /^\D+/g, ''));

    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {

        var finalprice = price * 1.15;

        jQuery('#totalfinal').text(finalprice.toFixed(2));

    } else {

        jQuery('#totalfinal').text(price.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
    $ 85 
</div>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="myBox2"  size="12" />
With Two Coat + 15%
<b><span id="totalfinal"></span> </b>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. https://imgur.com/undefined but its not showing anything :(